# apps script web app with Labview and limited domain access

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, labview

I didn't find a thread relative to my question.

I use a script to transfer data from Labview to google spreadsheet.

```js
function doPost(e){
  // Parse out the URL parameters
  var param=e.parameter;
  var time =param.time;
  var dA = param.dA;
  var dB = param.dB;
  var dC = param.dC;
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById('to replace by sheetID');
  var dAsheet=sheet.getSheetByName('dA').appendRow([time,dA]);
  var dBsheet=sheet.getSheetByName('dB').appendRow([time,dB]);
  var dCsheet=sheet.getSheetByName('dC').appendRow([time,dC]);
  var Main=sheet.getSheetByName('Main').appendRow([time,dA,dB,dC]);
}
```

code from : https://github.com/joseph280996/LabView-to-GoogleSpreadsheet

In labview I use the link of the published apps script as web app with an HTML function to run the script.

It work well with my personnal google account and the web app access configured as : "Anyone, even anonymous"

With my professional account I have a web app access limitation to "Anyone within "my domain"". With this configuration I cannot run the sript from a labview HTML request.

My question is how can I be "log-in" to execute this script with Labview?

I tried in the past to use the .net spreadsheet API but its dll cannot be used with labview.

More details about the dll issue :

I tried this code : https://github.com/ni/labview-gdrive
It works on my computer. I'm able to use the Google drive api. I wanted to do the same with the spreadsheet api. When I load the DLL with the .net constructor I got the following error :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IpTo.png)

If I download on Nuget the same dll as the gitub project (Google.Apis.Drive.v3.1.14.0.543), I have the same problem.

Regards.

Comment: Can you show some LabVIEW code (preferably as a [VI Snippet](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/9330/en/)? What was the problem with the spreadsheet API?

Comment: I edited my post with more details

Comment: If you cut down the example in your screenshot to finish at the `FileList` node, does that run OK and if so what data do you actually get out of its `Files` output?

Comment: The original project code works. The error appear when I try to select a new dll that I downloaded from Nuget by double click on `FilesRessource+ListRequest` .net assembly. So, I cannot run the VI by cutting down anything.
If you're motivated you can try with your PC to open this DLL with a .net assembly node [link to DDL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v3/)